# Configuring Web Service & thin client using Servlet+JSON+MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, json, tomcat

I have a Thin Client developed using Java SE. My Thin Client needs to connect to Web Server to:

1. Request information from database.
2. Send Update, insert, & delete Request.

Thin Client Will never connect to database directly.
After Reading & discussion on the internet I got the Following Highlighted Techniques:

1. Installing Database server (MySQL) & Creating my database.
2. Installing Web Server (Tomcat).
3. Moving the SQL Queries & Logic To the Web Server.
4. Web server will have Servlets which executes the SQL statements.
5. My Thin Client will request the results from web-server, the web-server will get data from MySQL database, & returning the result-set to my thin client using JSON Format.
6. Thin Client will decode The Format from JSON.
7. Working with data in my thin client then send back any updates to the web-server which reasonable about updating my database.

What i need:

- Is this the better way to do it, or there is another idea that we can work with.
- Do i need to use any other technologies to achieve this.
- Where i can get some working examples.
- I want to publish a fully working documentation to others to get benefit from it with simple steps without the need to search the internet for days.
- I hope all of you will share us.

Used Technology:

- Tomcat server.
- MySQL Server.
- Java SE for the thin client.
- Servlet for logic & database operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on something similar at work. Here is what we're doing to handle it.

We have a Web Client, what is analagous to your Thin Client, that needs information from a backend database. It does this by accessing a RESTful Web Service that will make database calls and return the information to the client in a JSON package.

Tools used:

- Spring-Roo: for rapid prototyping (http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)
- Spring Tool Suite
- Spring
- Maven
- Tomcat
- SqlServer
- Hibernate

All of these tools work really well together to develop a web service. Roo allows for quick development and easy ways to tie all the elements of the project together. And it works with more than SqlServer, hibernate, and Tomcat and doesn't require an IDE (altho Spring Tool Suite has a built in GUI shell), but it depends on Maven. I absolutely love it. It uses AspectJ for most of its magic, but once you get past the mystique of AspectJ, it becomes quite intuitive.

Heres a good tutorial for Roo : http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

Hope This helps!

EDIT: 
This is a repository that Roo with hibernate will create

Domain Entity:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity(table = "Example")
@RooJson
public class Example {

    private String name = "default";
    public Example(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.repositories;

import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.jpa.RooJpaRepository;

@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Example.class)
public interface ExampleRepository {
}
```

Once you have these, you create a Controller class that is able to execute HTTP requests like so:

```
@RooWebJson(jsonObject = Example.class)
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/example/")
public class ExampleController {
    @Resource
    ExampleRepository exampleRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value ="/{name}")
    public void putExample(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        exampleRepo.save(new Example(name));
    }
}
```

Calling the method `putExample()` is done by sending an Htpp PUT request to "http://{host}/example/somename". There are many more options for the RequestMapping, such as for specific headers contained in the request. JSON/xml from the request can also be handed to the service for use by the method.

Adding new queries can be done like so:

```
@Query("select * from Example e where e.name = ?1)
List<Example> getAllByName(String name);
```

Adding this method to the repository class will give you a new Sql query. Note: the queries are written in the JPA of choice language. This is the Hibernate way to do it.

There are some conventions related to RESTful services here. Such as, Http PUT and POST should only be used to do Sql UPDATE or INSERT queries, Http GET should be used for Sql SELECT, Http DELETE for Sql DELETE, etc., but its up to the web servicer designer.

I should clarify that Roo is a Rapid Application Development (RAD) kit. It can be used to prototype applications. You will need to do some programming, but it will be less.

Let me know if this helps clarify things!

Comment: That Really Cool, but i already have my ready thin client in java SE, i need to move the logic & SQL statement to server side, so the client just have the GUI. Request will go throw web-server to get responded from it. i don't want to create a web application, just i need to create a servlet for example which return JSON to my thin client.

Comment: That's basically what we're doing. The web service has no gui, it just handles http requests, e.g. the client will send a http GET to "http://host/service/" and the service will return a JSON package of whatever needs to be returned. The service itself just contains logic used to access the backend database.

Have you looked at using a RESTful web service for the server side application?

Comment: Yes, I read about RESTful & understand it, also JSON. So JSON will be my way to get data from database, But what about INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE?

Comment: That depends on which JPA you are using. Roo can make Repositories extended from JpaRepository which contains basic persistence methods such as save which will persist an Object for you. You can also write your own queries in the repository. I will post examples.

Comment: That what i was looking for since a very long time, you are brilliant